# Do entangled coherent states violates Heisenberg limit?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, metrology

In the ideal quantum information version of metrology, a maximally entangled
state is viewed as the best resource for quantum metrology. The optimal phase uncertainty of the NOON state reaches to the Heisenberg limit. Later we have seen that for same average particle number, an entangled coherent state (ECS) outperforms the phase enhancement achieved by NOON states
for small number of photons. Can we say that ECS violates the standard Heisenberg limit? If Heisenberg limit is standard then hoe coherent states give better phase measurement?